# changing wifi password over SSH on wifi-only headless server

Tags: linux, command-line, wifi, raspberry-pi, headless

I want to change the password for my wifi network `foo`.

I've got a raspberry pi connected to `foo`. I only use SSH to talk with it. The pi is headless, and it isn't convenient to attach a monitor+keyboard or hardline. `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` on the pi has lines like this:

```
network={
    ssid="foo"
    psk=deadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeef
}
```

Can I just duplicate that config with the new password? Like so:

```
network={
    ssid="foo"
    psk=deadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeef
}

network={
    ssid="foo"
    psk=abcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcd
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Yes

This works. The network manager will try connecting to each one.

Comment: @msp9011 it looks like a pretty definite answer to me.

Answer (score 2):

Additionally to that, Wifi configuration can be done easily via the [raspi-config](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#the-raspi-config-tool)

After connected via ssh:

```
sudo raspi-config
```

[image]